# Certificate validity range concerning subdomains

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

If I have a self-signed certificate for `something.subdomain.example.com` then it will not be valid on `www.subdomain.example.com`, right? (Note that the certificate is self-signed, but imported so it should be trusted)

Is a wildcard certificate the right solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct.

Your options are a wildcard certificate or Subject Alternative Names

A wildcard certificate for `*.subdomain.example.com` is valid for `www.subdomain.example.com` and `other.subdomain.example.com`, but NOT `www.othersubdomain.example.com`, and possibly not for just `subdomain.example.com` either (unless you also list it as a SAN).  It also will **not** work for `www.sub.sub.sub.subdomain.example.com`.

Or you can Subject Alternative Name to explicitly list all the subdomains you want it to work for.

Comment: Thank you very much, kind sir. Would vote you up, had I the reputation.